# NetworkInfo sale tachado, al detectar conectividad

Tags: android

Hola no se porque esta linea sale tachada: (NetworkInfo , getActiveNetworkInfo(), isConnected())

```
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
```

la version del compilador que tengo es la 29 en mi archivo `build.gradle`:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.valhondo.delgado.tesoreriainjurios"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Pero no se porque sale tachado.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**La razón por la que se muestran "tachado" es porque el uso de esos métodos es obsoleto**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes actualizar usando los nuevos métodos, si revisas la documentación la clase [NetworkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo) es obsoleta en API 29, por lo tanto sus métodos como [getActiveNetworkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetworkInfo()) también lo están.

Si usas como `targetSdkVersion = 29` entonces lo recomendable es cambiar el código para detectar conectividad, se realizaría de esta forma usando la clase `NetworkCapabilities`, usa el siguiente método:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
           NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    return true;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    return true;
                }  else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    return false;
}
```

El método anterior lo usarías de esta forma:

```
  //if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
  if (isOnline(getApplicationContext()){
     //Hay conexión
  }else{
     //NO hay conexión
  }
```